# Spring Data gemfire - More than one OnServer Function

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-gemfire

Is it possible to register more than one @OnServer Function Interface? When we enable more than one Function with @OnServer for Client side proxy, the server fails to start with below error.

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.data.gemfire.function.execution.GemfireOnServerFunctionTemplate#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.gemfire.function.execution.GemfireOnServerFunctionTemplate#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gemfireCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfireCache': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A connection to a distributed system already exists in this VM.  It has the following configuration:

The gemfire functions are placed in a package and below is added to the appContext for component-scanning.

```
<gfe-data:function-executions base-package="com.test.data.gemfire"/>
```

Is there a standard practice to register only 1 OnServer function (which sounds too restrictive)? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to register more than one @OnServer Function Interface?

Yes; absolutely!

> When we enable more than one Function with @OnServer for Client side proxy, **the server fails to start with below error.**

This a confused statement.  By server, I assume you mean the application, GemFire cache client JVM process.  `@OnServer` annotations are only applicable on a client and cannot be used on a "GemFire Server" (as in a peer cache member of the distributed system).

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A connection to a distributed system already exists in this VM. It has the following configuration:

This is a very old problem (and Exception caused by SDG) indicating that you are using an older version (i.e. < 1.7.0.RELEASE).

A similar problem was cited in [SGF-414](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-414) when using SSL between the client and server, with an initial fix released in `1.6.2.RELEASE` along with `1.7 RC1`.

Unfortunately, however, this did not solve the entire problem, so additional work was again performed for the SDG `1.8 RC1` release in [SGF-416](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-416) as well as [SGF-468](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-468).

Needless to say, this was a very complicated problem caused by GemFire's Distributed System configuration validation checks and the ability to configure the `ClientCache` and `Pool` as separate beans (i.e. by the presence of both `<gfe:client-cache>` and `<gfe:pool>` elements in a XML config file) in a *Spring* context, where proper coordination is required.

So my recommendation to you is, upgrade to the latest *Spring Data GemFire* release, which is **1.8.3.RELEASE**.  Also, the latest `1.7.5.RELEASE` should work, though I am not entirely certain.  You can an always find the latest information on *Spring Data GemFire's* [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/).

If you have additional questions or need help, let me know.

Thanks,
John